# How to include the environment variables for IBM CloudEngine create/update task via secret Manager (keyValue Secret value)

Tags: ibm-cloud-code-engine, ibm-secrets-manager

After successfully creating Secret Manager instance in IBMcloud. I have created a key-value secret in default secret-group, this secret contains the default set of environment variables which will be used for CodeEngine deployment.
However, I am now continuously facing issues with trying to deploy the app, i use the below command to deploy, let me know if there is anything wrong here

```
ibmcloud ce application create --name ce-sample-app --image IMAGE_NAME --cpu 1 --env-from-secret sample-portal-ce-app-env-variables --registry-secret xyxyxyxyxyxy
```

Answer (score 0):

The secrets that you reference in the Code Engine commands, are secrets managed in Code Engine directly rather than in a separate Secret Manager service instance.

Here is the documentation about secrets in Code Engine: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-configmap-secret

Basically you would need to create your secret like this:

```bash
ibmcloud ce secret create --name sample-portal-ce-app-env-variables --from-literal ENVVAR1=value1 --from-literal "ENVVAR2=value with space"
```

There are also options to import all environment variables from a file into a secret. To see all options, run:

```bash
ibmcloud ce secret create --help
```